# Coloring CGPoint of a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UIImage which I'd like to change some of the pixel-colors for by setting RGBA. I have CGPoints for all the pixels I need to change. How can I change the colors by setting a RGBA value?

If it's not possible to change the color of a UIImage pixel it would be okay to draw on the UIImageView containing the image, but I need it to perform quite well as I'm going to do it many times.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I figured out a solution for my problem. This colors a CGPoint red:

```
-(void)pixelate:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGImageRef inImage = self.drawImage.image.CGImage;
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if (cgctx == nil) { NSAssert(NO,@"Context shouldn't be nil!"); }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData(cgctx);
    if (data != nil)
    {
        int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        data[offset] = 255; //alpha
        data[offset+1] = 255; //red
        data[offset+2] = 0; //green
        data[offset+3] = 0; //blue
    }

    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgctx);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGContextRelease(cgctx);

    if (data) { free(data); }

    self.drawImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
}
```

Comment: Drawing performance is heavily dependent on access patterns. Setting pixels one at a time is generally not very efficient.  It would help to know what you are doing at a high level.

Comment: I'm trying to create a "bucket"-tool for at painting program. I figured a recursive method coloring pixel by pixel would do it. I'd be happy to hear about better solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for my problem. This colors a CGPoint red:

```
-(void)pixelate:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGImageRef inImage = self.drawImage.image.CGImage;
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if (cgctx == nil) { NSAssert(NO,@"Context shouldn't be nil!"); }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData(cgctx);
    if (data != nil)
    {
        int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        data[offset] = 255; //alpha
        data[offset+1] = 255; //red
        data[offset+2] = 0; //green
        data[offset+3] = 0; //blue
    }

    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cgctx);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGContextRelease(cgctx);

    if (data) { free(data); }

    self.drawImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Imaport following file..**>>>> Edited....**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8,bytesPerRow,             colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmContext, (CGRect){.origin.x = 0.0f, .origin.y = 0.0f, .size.width =     originalWidth, .size.height = originalHeight}, cgImage);
```

grab a reference to the underlying pixels :

```
UInt8* data = (UInt8*)CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmContext);
```

pixels operation :

```
const size_t bitmapByteCount = bytesPerRow * originalHeight;
for (size_t i = 0; i < bitmapByteCount; i += 4)
{
UInt8 a = data[i];
UInt8 r = data[i + 1];
UInt8 g = data[i + 2];
UInt8 b = data[i + 3];

data[i] = (UInt8)newAlpha
data[i + 1] = (UInt8)newRed;
data[i + 2] = (UInt8)newGreen;
data[i + 3] = (UInt8)newBlue;
}

CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmContext);
```

Or use this Refrence...

http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/

Hope, this will help you..enjoy

Comment: Thank you. Never really got your solution to work, but you made me look for the right solution. Thank you.

Comment: see the reference..it may help you...and you need to import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in your ViewController